# Select query for search with 2 or more words without double quotes in solr

Tags: select, solr, solr6

I have a column named title. I want to search this column. There is no problem when I use single word like `title:'sport'` OR  `title:"sport"`. Both giving same number of record.

My problem is when I search with 2 or more words without double quotes(with double quotes giving exact result ex: `title:"sport education"`).

`title:'sport education'` - returning irrelevant records(more title's don't have sport or education word)

`+title:'sport education'` -  returns the same number of record for the search of`title:'sport' / title:"sport"`.

what should I do to get atleast any one search word must match in the column?

**Note:** Solr version 6.3.0

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet what you are looking for is the following chain of parameters:

```
http://$solr_host:8983/solr/magazines/select&q=sport+education&df=title&q.op=OR
```

Let me decipher it for you:

- q=sport+education. You are free to use query in such free form.
- df=title. Here you are specifying default field for search.
- q.op=OR (which is default, feel free to omit it). `$q` will be tokenized according to `$df` fieldType and the clauses will be joined via OR like this: `title:sport OR title:education`

For more information you can follow [Common Query Parameters](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Common+Query+Parameters) or [Local Parameters in Queries](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Local+Parameters+in+Queries).

Comment: Looks perfect... Greatly appreciated! But this is working for one column. How can I implement the same for 2 or 3 columns?

Answer (score 1):

After parsing your query `title:'sport education'` will look like this

`title:sport` `text:education` single quote doesn't work as double quotes.

so term `education` is searched in default field `df`(text, check it in solr-config file)

In schema file you might have copied many other field into text using `copyfield` so you get other documents(fields which have education in it)

You should specify field name to search different term in different field like`title:sport name:sachin`.

In phrase query using double quotes `title:"sport education"` this gives you all documents with title field having `sport education` in it.

Comment: Thanks for your time and writing answer on my problem.