# Select query for search with 2 or more words without double quotes against more than one field in solr

Tags: select, solr, solr6

Please refer [My previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41156631/select-query-for-search-with-2-or-more-words-without-double-quotes-in-solr/41161530#41161530) .

With respect to the [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41161530/4684125) for my question, I could do with one filed.

I Could not able to do with multiple fields.

http://$solr_host:8983/solr/magazines/select&q=sport+education&df=title&q.op=OR - this is working for one field. How can I do it for multiple field.

What is the right way to achieve my objective. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Dismax/eDismax with `qf` (Query Fields) Parameter.

example:

```
http://$solr_host:8983/solr/magazines/select&q=sport+education&defType=edismax&qf=title name&q.op=OR
```

Check this [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+DisMax+Query+Parser)

Comment: Thank you for your answer and reference... Will check further and accept your answer if it help me to achieve my objective!